# Linear map on tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a map $f:\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{R} {\rm Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow {\rm Mat}(n,\mathbb{\mathbb{C}})$ defined by 
$$(z \otimes M)\mapsto zM $$

I was told that such a map is linear. But I cannot see after hours of playing how to write a sum $z \otimes M + w\otimes N$ in the form $v\otimes P$, and hence I cannot see how one shows that $f$ is indeed linear.

I know there does exist *a* linear map which satisfies $(z \otimes M)\mapsto zM $, but I'm trying to see if we can show its indeed this $f$, based on the definition alone.

Any tips?

Comment: $f$ takes $z\otimes M+w\otimes N$ to $zM+wN$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown But this is exactly what I want to prove. I only know what $f$ does to tensors $z\otimes M$, not to sums of such tensors.

Comment: But $f$ is linear.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ah I just reread the question and can see that maybe its not clear - I was told by a friend that this $f$ is linear. I don't believe them and want to prove that $f$ is linear.

Comment: The basic principle of tensor products is that linear maps from $A\otimes B$ correspond to bilinear maps from $A\times B$.